# link error with "undefined lua_xxxxx" when building lsnes

Tags: linux, hyperlink, lua

In my ubuntu 14.xx, I try to compile lsnes emulator to use the mario-ai script from [aleju/mario-ai](https://github.com/aleju/mario-ai), and I've tried to google many solutions to solve the problem below:

## Here is the output from the console:

> make[3]: `__all__.files' is up to date.
>   make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/platform/macosx'
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/platform'
>   g++ -o lsnes`cat **all_common**.files **all_platform**.files`-pthread -lboost_iostreams -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lz  -lgcrypt -lgpg-error  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl -rdynamic -ldl`cat core/**all**.ldflags lua/**all**.ldflags fonts/**all**.ldflags library/**all**.ldflags interface/**all**.ldflags video/**all**.ldflags emulation/**all**.ldflags cmdhelp/**all**.ldflags platform/**all**.ldflags
>   `core/multitrack.o: In function`lua::state::get_string(int, std::string const&)':
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/core/../../include/library/lua-base.hpp:317: undefined reference to `lua_tolstring'
>   core/multitrack.o: In function`lua::state::get_bool(int, std::string const&)':
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/core/../../include/library/lua-base.hpp:334: undefined reference to `lua_toboolean'
>   core/multitrack.o: In function`lua::state::type(int)':
>   .
>   .
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/library/lua.cpp:536: undefined reference to `lua_close'
>   library/lua.o: In function`lua::state::pushcfunction(int (*)(lua_State*))':
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/library/../../include/library/lua-base.hpp:504: undefined reference to `lua_pushcclosure'
>   library/lua.o: In function`lua::state::getfield(int, char const*)':
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/library/../../include/library/lua-base.hpp:506: undefined reference to `lua_getfield'
>   library/lua.o: In function`lua::state::insert(int)':
>   /home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src/library/../../include/library/lua-base.hpp:509: undefined reference to `lua_insert'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[1]: *** [lsnes] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/pengsuyu/software/lsnes/sourcecode/src'
>   make: *** [src/**all_files**] Error 2

## ==================================

At the beginning, I think, the linker cannot find my lua library. So I tried to compile my main.cpp with test.lua.

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//extern "C"
//{
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
//} // liblua5.1-c++.a 
lua_State * L;
int main ()
{
     L = lua_open();
     luaL_openlibs(L);
     luaL_dofile(L, "d:\\test.lua");
     return 0;
}
```

test.lua:

```
print("Hello World");
```

I write a MakeFile to generate the executable file "main":

```
main:main.o
    gcc -o $@ $< -llua5.1 -lstdc++
main.o:
    gcc -c main.cpp
clean:
    -rm *.o
```

It works when I add the compile option "-llua5.1" and "-lstdc++" otherwise it throws the same error as I compiled lsnes

I am not familiar with gcc and Makefile. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I've solved my question

The way to solve this problem is just to change one line in the file named "options.build".

```
1. find the line "LUA=lua" in options.build

2. change this line to "LUA=lua5.1"
```

because the needed library is 5.1, so if you want to build it successfully, you must use the "lua5.1" library however the default configuration is "lua" not "lua5.1"